# Implementing a pop up window

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Implementing centering feature for image downloads - Pop Up Window

I posted [here](http://how-to-obtain-50px-by-50px-image-from-user-input-image-x-x-y) asking a coding question on face recognition.  How do you get an x by y image to an x by x image.  The answer was easy let the user do it, this is how facebook does it.  I want to implement this as well.

The user uploads the image durring a one step sign up.  I want a pop up window to ask the user to center the image before taking them to the start screen.  How do I implement a pop up window with out using libraries?

Comment: Why are you not using any libraries? Homework or general self hate? lol

Comment: No need for a library, use the [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) method.

Comment: Why loading hundreds of kilobytes of trash, when something is done with a view lines of code?

Comment: @Lous - true, a bit of masochism

Comment: A popup `<div>` would look and function better than a window.

Comment: @Steve - a div's default appearance is transparent and it has almost none of the functionality of a window (try loading a URI into it). *window.open* is supported by pretty much every browser that ever supported javascript with zero extra code or cross browser issues.

Comment: @RobG and easily blocked by every browsers popup window blocker.  You can add an `iframe` to the `div` which Google frequently does.  You can shadow the underlying stack similar to Chrome's settings `div` based dialogs.

Comment: Most popup blockers will not prevent windows opened in response to user actions. I don't use popups at all, but they are a reasonable option for some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a life without jQuery? Yes it is!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup (url) {
  var yourwindow = window.open(url, "PopupwindowName", "width=400,height=300,resizable=yes");
  yourwindow.focus();
  return false;
}
</script>

call:
<a href="popup.htm" target="_blank" onclick="return popup(this.href);">show popup</a>
```

Comment: window.open provides a horrible experience. It's much better to append an element to the DOM rather then create a new window.

Comment: @djlumley - users can open new windows in a tab or new window at their discretion. Windows and tabs can be re-used, linked to other domains, be resized, raised or lowered by the user and so on. None of that comes with a div. Try loading a URI from another domain into a div.

Comment: @RobG - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Iframe and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/resize While I agree there are rare situations where creating a new window provides a better experience, modal windows provide a much better user experience, for the most part, and you'd be hard pressed to find a user who didn't agree.

Comment: If you load a resource into an iFrame you still have a featureless container that can't be moved, resized, minimized and so on without significant additional code, nor does it have the entirely independant nature of a window or tab. Depending on CSS 3 (which is *still* not a stanrdard) features that are only supported by a small number of very new browsers is not a good idea on the web.